# R - Need help to split by column keyword or group by keyword then loop with if else calculation and merge back or ungroup

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, group-by, split

I currently have dataframe summary2. And I have a for loop which calculates a mean, based on the number of rows before current row. But I need to do this loop based on unique keywords (drink food etc). If not the first food rows will use numbers from drink to calculate.
I tried to use split and group_by but it was not successful.

**Summary2 dataframe:**
*keywords - hits - date*
drink - 4 - 01-01-2016
drink - 5 - 01-02-2016
drink - 8 - 01-03-2016
drink - 4 - 01-04-2016
drink - 5 - 01-05-2016
drink - 8 - 01-06-2016
drink - 4 - 01-07-2016
drink - 5 - 01-08-2016
drink - 8 - 01-09-2016
drink - 4 - 01-10-2016
drink - 5 - 01-11-2016
drink - 8 - 01-12-2016
food - 4 - 01-01-2016
food - 5 - 01-02-2016
food - 8 - 01-03-2016
food - 4 - 01-04-2016
food - 5 - 01-05-2016
food - 8 - 01-06-2016
food - 4 - 01-07-2016
food - 5 - 01-08-2016
food - 8 - 01-09-2016
food - 4 - 01-10-2016
food - 5 - 01-11-2016
food - 8 - 01-12-2016

Loop code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(summary2)) {
  if (i < "3") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[i:(i+3)])
  }
  else if (i == "3") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-2)])
  }
  else if (i == "4") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-3)])
  }
  else if (i == "5") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-4)])
  }
  else if (i == "6") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-4)])
  }
  else if (i == "7") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-5)])
  }
  else if (i == "8") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-6)])
  }
  else if (i == "9") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-7)])
  }
  else if (i == "10") {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-7)])
  }
  
  else {
    summary2$median[i] = median(summary2$hits[(i-1):(i-8)])
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some coding "nudges" I suggest:

1. You have a `for` loop that iterates over integers, don't compare `i` with a string. While R will eventually do what you think you need, there are a few things you should know. First, your inequality test is subject to lexicographic comparisons, not numeric ones, so while `20 < 3` is true, `"20" < "3"` is not. Second, in general I think it's just best practice to be explicit about the type/class of variables you're expecting to use, do the first conditional would be just `if (i < 3)`.
2. This is a moving-window median, which is fine. But it is inconsistent; this might be by-design, but as an analyst I find it difficult to explain that a number is a median of the last so-many-values unless it's at the beginning, in which case it is the median of the *following* values ... which is somewhat anathema to some time-series practices. Options for rolling calcs for the first few values (smaller than the window size) include: omitting them (not friendly for `data.frame`; replacing them with `NA` until you have enough values for the vector; or allow partial windows (where if you're expecting a window size of 5, then the first value would be a median of itself, second a median of the first two, etc).

I'll import those thoughts into my code, and end up with below. First, the standard package for rolling-window calcs in R has been for a long time the `zoo::rollapply` family of functions. (A recent newcomer to the field is the `slider` package; I don't have experience with it yet, but it offers many features that `zoo` does not.)

First, I'll demo this on just the `"drink'` data, in rows `1:12`. The `9` is the window size: since you want from `i-1` to `i-8` in general, then you need 9, which is the previous 8 plus the current value. Since you don't want to include the current value in the median, we'll exclude it in the calcs.

```r
zoo::rollapply(summary2$hits[1:12], 9, function(z) median(z[-length(z)], na.rm = TRUE), align = "right")
# [1] 5 5 5 5
```

There were 12 values but we only returned 4 ... that's because it needed to go a bit into the data before it had enough to do a full window or 9. One of the remedies I suggested is a partial window:

```r
zoo::rollapply(summary2$hits[1:12], 9, function(z) median(z[-length(z)], na.rm = TRUE), align = "right", partial = TRUE)
#  [1]  NA 4.0 4.5 5.0 4.5 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0
```

which is what we'll use. The `NA` is not unexpected: since are general rule is take everything before the current, then the first one has nothing ... so it has no values to `median`.

Since you want the first few to look "forward" in time a little (I mentioned it in the nudge #2 above), we'll write a function that does this and then compensates for the first few values.

```r
func <- function(x, k = 9) {
  out <- zoo::rollapply(x, k, function(z) median(z[-length(z)], na.rm = TRUE), align = "right", partial = TRUE)
  out[ seq_len(min(2, length(x))) ] <- median(head(x, 4), na.rm = TRUE)
  out
}
```

now our return for `"drink"` looks like:

```r
func(summary2$hits[1:12])
#  [1] 4.5 4.5 4.5 5.0 4.5 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0
```

Now, to do this by `"keywords"`, we can use `ave`:

```r
summary2$rollmedian <- ave(summary2$hits, summary2$keywords, FUN = func)
summary2
#    keywords hits        date rollmedian
# 1     drink    4  01-01-2016        4.5
# 2     drink    5  01-02-2016        4.5
# 3     drink    8  01-03-2016        4.5
# 4     drink    4  01-04-2016        5.0
# 5     drink    5  01-05-2016        4.5
# 6     drink    8  01-06-2016        5.0
# 7     drink    4  01-07-2016        5.0
# 8     drink    5  01-08-2016        5.0
# 9     drink    8  01-09-2016        5.0
# 10    drink    4  01-10-2016        5.0
# 11    drink    5  01-11-2016        5.0
# 12    drink    8  01-12-2016        5.0
# 13    food     4  01-01-2016        4.5
# 14    food     5  01-02-2016        4.5
# 15    food     8  01-03-2016        4.5
# 16    food     4  01-04-2016        5.0
# 17    food     5  01-05-2016        4.5
# 18    food     8  01-06-2016        5.0
# 19    food     4  01-07-2016        5.0
# 20    food     5  01-08-2016        5.0
# 21    food     8  01-09-2016        5.0
# 22    food     4  01-10-2016        5.0
# 23    food     5  01-11-2016        5.0
# 24    food     8  01-12-2016        5.0
```

---

Data

```r
summary2 <- structure(list(keywords = c("drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food ", "food "), hits = c(4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8), date = c(" 01-01-2016", " 01-02-2016", " 01-03-2016", " 01-04-2016", " 01-05-2016", " 01-06-2016", " 01-07-2016", " 01-08-2016", " 01-09-2016", " 01-10-2016", " 01-11-2016", " 01-12-2016", "01-01-2016", "01-02-2016", "01-03-2016", "01-04-2016", "01-05-2016", "01-06-2016", "01-07-2016", "01-08-2016", "01-09-2016", "01-10-2016", "01-11-2016", "01-12-2016")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Thanks. Ended up with this solution:  
`summary3 <- summary3 %>% group_by(keyword) %>% mutate(median8 = rollapply(data=hits, width = list(c(-8,-7, -6, -5, -4,-3, -2, -1)), median, fill = NA), median4 = rollapply(data=hits, width = list(c(-4,-3, -2, -1)), median, fill = NA), median12 = rollapply(data=hits, width = list(c(-12,-11-10,-9,-8,-7, -6, -5, -4,-3, -2, -1)), median, fill = NA))`
(Can't figure out how to add a linebreak in comments)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that for the first 2 points you want to take the median of that point and the next 3 points.  For the remaining points you want to take the median of the prior 8 points or if 8 points are not available then however many exist.

Here w is a list such that the ith component defines the offsets to use for the i-th element.  Offset 0 means current point, offset 1 is next point and so on.
-1 is the prior point and so on. For i=1 and i=2 we want to use seq(0, 3) as the offsets which means the current point and the next 3.  For all others we use -seq(8) which means the prior 8 points. partial = TRUE means that if there are not 8 points prior or 3 points subsequent use however many exist.  For example if there were 5 rows in a keyword then w would be `list(seq(0,3), seq(0,3), -seq(9), -seq(8), -seq(8))` for that keyword.

We use ave to separately apply rollapply to each keyword's hits using the w described above. (continued after code and output)

```
library(zoo)

roll <- function(x) {
  w <- ifelse(seq_along(x) < 3, list(seq(0, 3)), list(-seq(8)))
  rollapply(x, w, median, partial = TRUE)
}
transform(summary2, median = ave(hits, keywords, FUN = roll))
```

giving:

```
   keywords hits        date median
1     drink    4  01-01-2016    4.5
2     drink    5  01-02-2016    5.0
3     drink    8  01-03-2016    4.5
4     drink    4  01-04-2016    5.0
5     drink    5  01-05-2016    4.5
6     drink    8  01-06-2016    5.0
7     drink    4  01-07-2016    5.0
8     drink    5  01-08-2016    5.0
9     drink    8  01-09-2016    5.0
10    drink    4  01-10-2016    5.0
11    drink    5  01-11-2016    5.0
12    drink    8  01-12-2016    5.0
13     food    4  01-01-2016    4.5
14     food    5  01-02-2016    5.0
15     food    8  01-03-2016    4.5
16     food    4  01-04-2016    5.0
17     food    5  01-05-2016    4.5
18     food    8  01-06-2016    5.0
19     food    4  01-07-2016    5.0
20     food    5  01-08-2016    5.0
21     food    8  01-09-2016    5.0
22     food    4  01-10-2016    5.0
23     food    5  01-11-2016    5.0
24     food    8  01-12-2016    5.0
```

Alternately the grouping could be done using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

summary2 %>%
  group_by(keywords) %>%
  mutate(median = roll(hits)) %>%  # roll defined previously
  ungroup
```

### Note

```
summary2 <- structure(list(keywords = c("drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", 
"drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", "drink", 
"drink", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", "food", 
"food", "food", "food", "food", "food"), hits = c(4, 5, 8, 4, 
5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8, 4, 5, 8), 
    date = c("01-01-2016", "01-02-2016", "01-03-2016", "01-04-2016", 
    "01-05-2016", "01-06-2016", "01-07-2016", "01-08-2016", "01-09-2016", 
    "01-10-2016", "01-11-2016", "01-12-2016", "01-01-2016", "01-02-2016", 
    "01-03-2016", "01-04-2016", "01-05-2016", "01-06-2016", "01-07-2016", 
    "01-08-2016", "01-09-2016", "01-10-2016", "01-11-2016", "01-12-2016"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```