# R median for past 4,8,12 rows - for loop and group not working, df filter not working as well

Tags: r, loops, filter, subset, median

I need to calculate different medians of past 4,8,12 weeks (weeks are even numbers). But the group by is not working in for loop. See code below.

I have a dataframe:

```
keyword - hits - date  
wine - 23 - 01.01.2020    
wine - 20 - 01.08.2020  
wine - 5 - 01.15.2020  
food - 21 - 01.01.2020  
food - 8 - 01.08.2020  
food - 4 - 01.15.2020  
other - 19 - 01.01.2020  
other - 12 - 01.08.2020  
other - 11 - 01.15.2020  
etc...

summary3 <- summary2 %>% group_by(keyword)
for (i in 1:nrow(summary3)) {
  if (i < "9") {
  summary3$median8[i] = i
  }
  else
     summary3$median8[i] = median(summary3$hits[(i-1):(i-8)])
}
for (i in 1:nrow(summary3)) {
  if (i < "5") {
    summary3$median4[i] = i
  }
  else
    summary3$median4[i] = median(summary3$hits[(i-1):(i-4)])
}
for (i in 1:nrow(summary3)) {
  if (i < "13") {
    summary3$median12[i] = i
  }
  else if (i < "13") {
    summary3$median12[i] = median(summary3$hits[(i-1):(i-12)])
  }
}
```

I also tried the dataframe filer method. But the PID is not correct displaying when I try to subtrack 1 and 8. PID = identify rows in each keyword group.

```
#summary3 <- summary2 %>% group_by(keyword) %>% mutate(pid = row_number())

#summary3$median8 <- median(summary3$hits[lag(summary3$pid, k=1) : lag(summary3$pid), k=8])
```

or this

```
#summary3$median8 <- median(summary3$hits[(summary3$pid-1) : (summary3$pid)-8])
```

Does anyone have a smart solution? I know there is a rollmedian but that is for odd numbers week.

Comment: Hi, could you please make your example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? At the moment it produces many errors like `Unknown or uninitialised column`... Also, to share data, please use `dput()` so if there is a format problem it is easier to spot it. In addition, you should apply recommendations from the answer on your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67424530/10264278

Answer (score 0):

The following is based on a `{tidyverse}`, i.e. `{dplyr}`, and the nice "rolling window" `{runner}` package. The latter saves you from creating and adapting the week ids (or PID) and then iterating over them.

I need to simulate some data, as you have not provided a reproducible example. But you can readily apply this to your data. I also constrain my example to the 4 and 8 weeks ...

```
library(dplyr)

# simulate some data
set.seed(666)

# create weekly timeseries
dates <- seq(from = lubridate::ymd("2020-01-01"), to = lubridate::ymd("2020-05-01")
             ,by = "1 week")

# example dataframe with weeks, the wine/food/other, and some random hits
df <- data.frame(
  keyword = c( rep("wine", length.out = length(dates))
              ,rep("food", length.out = length(dates))
              ,rep("other", length.out = length(dates))
  )
  , hits = sample(4:25, size = 3 * length(dates), replace = TRUE) # random integers
  , date = rep(dates, times = 3)
)
```

With `{runner}` calculate the rolling mean over the last 4 and 8 weeks.

```
library(runner)

df %>%
  group_by(keyword) %>%
  mutate(
    ROLL_MEAN_LAST4 = runner(
       x = hits
      ,k = "4 weeks"
      ,idx = date
      ,f = mean
    )
   , ROLL_MEAN_LAST8 = runner(
       x = hits
      ,k = "8 weeks"
      ,idx = date
      ,f = mean
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This yields

```
# A tibble: 54 x 5
   keyword  hits date       ROLL_MEAN_LAST4 ROLL_MEAN_LAST8
   <chr>   <int> <date>               <dbl>           <dbl>
 1 wine       14 2020-01-01           14               14  
 2 wine       17 2020-01-08           15.5             15.5
 3 wine        8 2020-01-15           13               13  
 4 wine       12 2020-01-22           12.8             12.8
 5 wine       15 2020-01-29           13               13.2
 6 wine        4 2020-02-05            9.75            11.7
 7 wine       21 2020-02-12           13               13  
 8 wine        6 2020-02-19           11.5             12.1
 9 wine        8 2020-02-26            9.75            11.4
10 wine       16 2020-03-04           12.8             11.2
```

Note: Check the runner documentation if you need to offset your rolling windows, etc. I.e. the solution calculates the mean for the partial time horizon (first week mean based on a single week, 2nd week mean based on the first 2 weeks).